# law of independent assortment

Tags: genetics, homework

Self fetilization of F<sub>1</sub> dihybrids, following independent assortment of alleles result in:

```
a) 3/16 Tall-rounds ; 3/16 dwarf-wrinkled
b) 9/16 Tall-wrinkled ; 3/16 dwarf-round
c) 9/16 Tall-round ; 3/16 dwarf-round
d) 3/16 Tall-wrinkled ; 3/16 dwarf-round
```

This question was asked in MCAT exam in Pak for which I'm preparing this year.... no genetic arcitecture was mentioned in question... The above mentioned is original format of question.... in ans-key, the ans is D but I am confused why it can't be C.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please do not post text as images. Images are not searcheable and pose problem to people with visual impairement.

Comment: Why do you think it could be C and not D? What is your logic?

Comment: Can you give more information about the genetic architecture underlying  these two phenotypic traits?

Comment: in my point of view, tall is dominant trait. so it can be C

Comment: The genetic architecture of these trait is not subject to a point of view. It must be defined in the question. Patterns of allele relationships must be defined, and given the choice of answer, the two loci must be linked, therefore information about their linkage must also be included. Also, your logic for answer C does not explain the round vs wrinkled part of the question.

Comment: this question was asked in MCAT Exam in Pak... but unfortunately this is the original question ..no genetic architecture was mentioned

Comment: Can you please link to this exam if available online? Also, please change your image into a text. I doubt anyone is willing to make any effort to help you if you don't show any effort.

Comment: no link is not available online... :(

Comment: @Remi.b I disagree with the fact that loci must be linked in that example, this is about phenotype not genotype, so with dominance effect we could indeed observe these 3/16 or 9/16.

Comment: Why was this upvoted. The question is unclear or incomplete (not necessarily OP's fault) and shows no effort at explaining the logic behind the suggested answer. IMO, the question should be closed either as unclear or as homework question showing no attempt at an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In real life, round and tall are dominant traits in pea plants, which would make C and D both correct.  I don't think people are expected to memorize the traits of pea plants, so the question ought to tell you somewhere which traits are dominant.  There must be an error in the question as printed.

Comment: In virtual life, A is also possible if we have Tall and wrinkeld as dominant alleles. B is impossible even in virtual as Tall and wrinkled would be the dominant and dwarf-round will present 1/16 occurence. I would say like you that the question has an error in it.